# C++/SDL Gravity in Platformer

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm currently trying to get a form of gravity (it doesn't need to be EXACTLY gravity, no realism required) into my platformer game, however I'm stumbling over logic on this.

The following code is what I use when the up arrow or W is pressed, (jumping)

```
if (grounded_)
{
    velocity_.y -= JUMP_POWER;
    grounded_ = false;
}
```

In my `Player::Update()` function I have

```
velocity_.y += GRAVITY;
```

There's more in that function but it's irrelevant to the situation.

Currently the two constants are as follows: `GRAVITY = 9.8f;` and `JUMP_POWER = 150.0f;`

The main issue I'm having with my gravity that I cannot find the proper balance between my sprite being able to make his jumps, and being way too floaty.

Long story short, my questions is that my sprite's jumps as well as his regular falling from one platform to another are too floaty, any ideas on how to scale it back to something a tad more realistic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of thinking in terms of the actual values, think in terms of their consequences.

So, the initial velocity is -jump_power, and the acceleration gravity. A little calculus gives

```
y = -Height = -jump_power * t + 1/2 * gravity * t^2
```

This assumes a small time step.

Then, the

```
time_in_flight = 2 * time_to_vertex = jump_power/gravity
```

and the vertex is

```
height(time_to_vertex) = jump_power^2/(4 * gravity)
```

Solving these, and adjusting for time step and fixing negatives

```
jump_power = (4 * height / time) * timestep_in_secs_per_update

gravity = (2 * jump_power / time) * timestep_in_secs_per_update
```

That way, you can mess with time and height instead of the less direct parameters. Just use the equations to gravity and jump_power at the start.

```
const int time = 1.5; //seconds
const int height = 100 //pixels

const int jump_power = (4 * height / time) * timestep_in_secs_per_update;
const int gravity = (2 * jump_power / time) * timestep_in_secs_per_update;
```

This is a technique from maths, often used to rearrange a family of differential equations in terms of 'dimensionless' variables. This way the variables won't interfere when you try to manipulate the equations characteristics. In this case, you can set the time and keep it constant while changing the power. The sprite will still take the same time to land.

Of course 'real' gravity might not be the best solution. You could set gravity low and just lower the character's height while they are not grounded.

Comment: Much like the answer above, it's still quite floaty.

Comment: @AndrewB this is really just your own solution rearranged so if you can't get it to look good with this, then you can't get it to look good with any 'parabolic' trajectory. personally (after fixing the syntax errors), i got ok looking results for low, fast jumps, and when i added a horizontal component they looked even better

Answer (score 0):

You need think unit system correctly.

1. The unit of the gravity is meter per second squared. ( m/(s*s) )
2. The unit of a velocity is meter per second. ( m/s )
3. The unit of a force is Newton. ( N = kg*m/(s*s) )

Concept example:

```
float gravity = -9.8; // m/(s*s)
float delta_time = 33.333333e-3f; // s
float mass = 10.0f; // Kg
float force = grounded_ ? 150.0f : gravity; // kg*m/(s*s)
float acceleration = force / mass; // m/(s*s)
float velocity += acceleration * delta_time; // m/s
float position += velocity * delta; // m
```

It is based on the basic Newton's Equation of motion and Euler's Method.

Comment: No matter what I do with this it still ends up being as floaty as it was before.